# Webform/YAML Form component email mapping

Tags: 8, webforms

In Drupal 7, [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module have the ability to map different emails against webform component's options so that the webform notification could be sent to different emails depending on a user selection.

[image: webform email handler settings]

In Drupal 8, Webform was ported and its email submission settings pretty basic so I decided to use [YAML Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/yamlform). However, YAML Form email handler have the ability to either have a custom emails separated by comma or a value from the component.

[image]

Is there a way to have component email mapping functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature has been added to the latest dev release of Webform-8.x-5.x.

@see [Issue #2854021 by jrockowitz: Send email based on element options selection](https://www.drupal.org/node/2854021)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the functionality is not inbuilt to web forms UI but it can still be done with a custom module.

Following the [webform recpie on handlers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform-8x-5x/recipe-how-to-programmatically-alter-destination-email-address) you can create a custom email handler like so:

Folder/File structure:

- ModuleName

  - src

    - Plugin
    - WebformHandler

      - MODULENAMEWebformHandler.php
  - MODULENAME.info.yml

Content example for MODULENAMEWebformHandler.php

```
namespace Drupal\MODULENAME\Plugin\WebformHandler;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandler\EmailWebformHandler;

/**
* Emails a webform submission.
*
* @WebformHandler(
*   id = "test_email",
*   label = @Translation("New Email"),
*   category = @Translation("Notification"),
*   description = @Translation("Send email depending on dropdown value"),
*   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
*   results = \Drupal\webform\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
* )
*/
class MODULENAMEWebformHandler extends EmailWebformHandler {

  public function sendMessage(array $message) {

    $form_data = $message['webform_submission']->getData('dropdown_id');

    switch($form_data) {

     case 'APAC':
       $recipient = 'apac@example.nl';
     break;

     case 'US':
       $recipient = 'us@example.ru';
     break;

     default:
       $recipient = 'default@example.com';
     break;

    }
    $message['to_mail'] = $recipient;

    parent::sendMessage($message);
  }
}
```